# [SOLVED]:'Unknown Error' when sending a POST request to my Spring Boot API Gateway from my Angular app and CORS is configured correctly

Tags: java, angular, spring-boot, cors, api-gateway

I'm "Getting 'Http failure response for http://localhost:8080/api/user/auth/login: 0 Unknown Error' when sending a POST request to my Spring Boot API Gateway from my Angular app. CORS is configured correctly, and the same request works fine when sent directly to the user-service. The API Gateway logs don't show any errors, and the browser console doesn't provide additional insights. Any suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue?".

**API Gateway application.properties**

```
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=true
eureka.client.fetch-registry=true
spring.application.name=api-gateway
eureka.client.service-url.defaultZone= http://localhost:8761/eureka
server.port=8080
## LOGS
logging.level.root=INFO
#class responsible for defining and identifying routes
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway.route.RouteDefinitionLocator = INFO
logging.level.org.springframework.cloud.gateway = TRACE
## END LOGS

## Routes
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].id=user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].uri = lb://user-service
spring.cloud.gateway.routes[0].predicates[0]=Path=/api/user/**
```

**Console error:**
[image]

**API GatewayCors config**

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.CorsRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurer;

@Configuration
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**")
                .allowedOrigins("*") // Replace with your Angular application's URL
                .allowedMethods("GET", "POST", "PUT", "DELETE")
                .allowedHeaders("Content-Type", "Authorization");
    }
}
```

**PS:** When I change the URL in my angular app to directly send a request to the user-service everything works fine.

Comment: Your gateway needs to allow CORS.

Comment: I already added the cors config to my api-gateway @MatthieuRiegler

Comment: Did you try running the gateway with debug logging enabled? If there’s an error, there’s going to be corresponding logging for it. The other option is to simply debug the gateway using a debugger. I’ve had to do that in the past myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please create an application.yml file in your api-gateway and place the following configuration inside.

```html
spring:
  application:
    name: gateway

  cloud:
    gateway:
      global-cors:
        corsConfigurations:
          '[/**]':
            allowedOrigins: "*"
            allowedMethods:
              - GET
              - POST
              - PUT
              - DELETE
              - PATCH
            allowedHeaders:
              - "Origin"
              - "Content-Type"
              - "Accept"
              - "Authorization"
              - "User-Key"
              - "Request-Tracker"
              - "Session-Tracker"
              - "X-XSRF-TOKEN"
              - "X-IBM-CLIENT-ID"
              - "Message-ID"
              - "X-IBM-CLIENT-SECRET"
      default-filters:
        - DedupeResponseHeader=Access-Control-Allow-Credentials Access-Control-Allow-Origin, RETAIN_FIRST
```

Comment: Yes, that fixed the problem. Apparently, the CORS config file doesn't work with the API Gateway because there is no controller in this service. CORS configuration needs to be done in the application.properties file